# close the modal popup in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

this is my bootstrap modal code

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="addform" id="formid">
    <div id="myModal" >
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Add Question</h3>
    </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="button"  onClick="aj_add_question(<?=$id?>);" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_button" name="Add" value="Add Question">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">cancel</button>
    </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="button"  value="Add Page"  onclick="aj_add_page();" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">cancel</button>
    </div>
 </form>
```

now onclick

> Add Question

i have  to close current popup

then i have written code

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
alert("Question Added..");
$('#formid').hide();
});
</script>
```

it will hide but get screen black

Comment: Try close the modal as `$('#myModal').modal('hide');`

Comment: Try this: $("#modal").modal("hide");

Comment: updated my edit close the modal with model id not the form id `$('#myModal').modal('hide');`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using modal popup syntax properly, can you try the following:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mymodaltitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              **--- put your form here**
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then, as others have suggested use **$("#mymodal").modal('hide')**